# Image not displaying correctly in Blade Laravel template

Tags: laravel

I need to generate qr-code and for this I use this package https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode

qr-code is generated in png format and I save it to the right place in the file system. Also, I write the path to this file into the database. The file path is always `'../storage/app/public/' . Auth::user()->id . '/qr.png'`. Every time a new file is generated, I overwrite the old one.

The problem is this. In the template, I am trying to display this image in the saved path and it is displayed but not correctly.

For example, I have a qr-code in a template, next I generate a new one and expect to see it, but the old image is displayed, which has been overwritten. Normal reloading of the web page does not help. Everything works correctly if you reload the `cntr+f5` page

Is it a cache issue or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a laravel issue, it's a browser "feature".

Have you tried to add a parameter to the image path to force browser do not cache the response?

```php
<img src="{{ url('/storage/' . Auth::user()->id . '/qr.png?v=' . time()) }}" alt="My newest QR code">
```

Comment: Thank you, I did as you suggested, but a little differently